# What is the relationship between aleph 1 and aleph 2?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, infinity

What is the mathematical relationship between aleph 1 and aleph 2,
(except for the fact that, if the Continuum Hypothesis is assumed, 2 to the power of aleph 1 equals aleph 2?)

Comment: $\aleph_2$ is the next cardinal of $\aleph_1$, but there is no other obvious relation between them. Especially, the continuum hypothesis says nothing about the value of $2^{\aleph_1}$.

Comment: I mean, other than we know a set of size $2^{\aleph_1},$ what would you want to know?

Comment: If $S$ is a set of cardinality $\aleph_1$, then $\aleph_2$ is the cardinality of the set of all isomorhism types of well-orderings of $S$.

Comment: Probably means the generalize continuum hypothesis, @HanulJeon

Comment: @HanulJeon Then why does one have to accept the "next" transfinite cardinal after aleph 1? Shouldn't there be some generative mechanism that allows you to get aleph 2 from aleph 1? (Just as we get the natural number 2 from 1 by the operator +1?)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Isn't that true only if we assume the Continuum Hypothesis?

Comment: @bof Oh, thanks. So that's what I was looking for. Is there a easier version of the same thing by any chance?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews gives how to 'construct' $\aleph_2$ from $\aleph_1$: collecting all ordinals of cardinality $\aleph_1$ results in $\omega_2$, which also is $\aleph_2$.

Comment: You said “given the continuum hypothesis” in the question. I took that as a given. Clarify your question if you didn’t mean that condition to be universal to the question. @Anti-Tachyon

Comment: So, my question can be rephrased as: "How do we define aleph 2 in terms of aleph 1 without assuming the continuum hypothesis or using the trivial notion of 'the next'?"

Comment: Then edit your question.

Comment: @HanulJeon Perfect, thank you!

Comment: But as a rule, without the continuum hypothesis, we know very little about any of the $\aleph_n,$ $n\geq 1,$ other than $\aleph_{n+1}\leq  2^{\aleph_n}.$

Comment: @HanulJeon  "collecting all ordinals of cardinality $\aleph_1$ results in $\omega_2$, which is $\aleph_2$" --> Does this means that if you collect all ordinals of cardinality $\aleph_1$, then the 'smallest' ordinal corresponding to that collection is $\omega_2$, and that is also $\aleph_2$?

Comment: In fact, the set of all ordinals of cardinality $\le\aleph_1$ is an ordinal. (My previous comment was loose at that point.) We call it $\omega_2$, and yes, it is also $\aleph_2$ (that is, we have two different names for the same set.)